# Rendering collections within collection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is driving me crazy, I thought it should be something very simple but I've spent all day trying to figure it out and getting nowhere. I've looked all over, there's something I must be missing.

I want to render a partial for a collection, within a partial from a collection.

Eg. I have a collection of `entries` which I want to render in my `feed` partial, I want `feed` to come from a collection of `feeds`, such that the page displays all entries in all feeds.

How can I do this?

Something like:

controller:

```
@feeds = Feeds.all
```

allmyfeeds.html.erb

```
@feeds.each do |feed|
<%= render 'feed' %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= render 'feeds', collection: @feeds %>
```

_feed.html.erb

```
<%= render 'items', collection: @items %>
```

_item.html.erb

```
<%= item.summary.html_safe %>
```

But I really don't know.

Comment: Please post your current implementation to your question.

Comment: Updated with something. I don't really have a current implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehting like:

```
<% @feeds.each do |feed| %>
  <%= render partial: 'feed', locals: { feed: feed } %>
<% end %>
```

In your `_feed.html.erb`:

```
<h1><%= feed.id %> </h1>
<% feed.entries.each do |entry| %>
  <&= render partial: 'entry', locals: { entry: entry } %>
<% end %>
```

In your `_entry.html.erb`:

```
<h2><%= entry.id %></h2>
```

I'm assuming your `Feed` model has a `has_many :entries` association, if it's not the case (and what you want is to render the same collection of `@entries` in each feed), then you just need to pass the `@entries` collection to the `_feed.html.slim` partial, like:

```
render partial: 'feed`, locals: { feed: feed, entries: @entries }
```

and update your `_feed.html.erb`

Answer (score 1):

Partial naming conventions will really help you out here...

In `allmyfeeds.html.erb` (which i'm guessing is actually `feeds/index.html.erb`), instead of this...

```
@feeds.each do |feed|
  <%= render 'feed' %>
<% end %>
```

You can simply call this...

```
<%= render @feeds %>  # this will invoke _feed.html.erb for every feed in the collection, automatically
```

Inside your `_feed.html.erb` partial...

```
# Note: You may need to change `items` to something like `items/items` if it is not located in the same directory
<%= render partial: 'items', locals: { items: feed.items } %>
```

Then in your items partial, you will have access to `items`, which is a collection of items for that particular feed

Comment: Thank you for your help Mark, locals: { items: feed.items } is something that eluded me today, we are not quite where I am hoping to get yet..

At the end of your steps, I am left with a collection. I want my _item partial to represent one item out of the collection of items.

Comment: gasc's comment works for what I was trying to achieve. Is it possible to "combine" these solutions so that I don't need to use a block in my _feed partial?

Comment: Yes, just follow the same logic. Read up on it [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) if you are stuck.